# Updating gmail contextual gadgets to the OAuth2

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a gmail gadget in apps marketplace that use SSO authorization described on this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/best_practices?csw=1#gadget_sso. With recent update of marketplace is gadget flow will be updated to OAuth2 or it will stay the same?

If yes, then what is the deadline for the migration? I wasn't able to find this on the documentation about release.

Thank you!

Comment: did you manage to configure a contextual gadget using the new appsmarket sdk ?

Comment: I'm using 'osapi.http.get' call to make a login request. Not sure is it a part of appsmarket sdk. Thank you.

Comment: what i mean is : cloud.google.com -> enable appsmarket sdk -> click gear icon -> configure COB extension; it screwes up my api console.

Comment: No, I'm not using this.

Comment: @koma I never got this to work with the new sdk. Were you able to?

Answer (score 0):

In the new marketplace setup, you still have to use a popup to setup the correlation between the opensocial Id and the google user. But the popup will no longer use OpenId/SSO to identify the user to the application. Instead these two OAUTH2 scopes are pre-authorized :

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

and that's enough to get the identity of the user.

Comment: why do we need to setup a popup with OAuth2? Can we not use gadget.io.makerequest with these two scopes to get the email address without consent?

Comment: any gadget.io.makerequest calls are proxied by the gadget container and any headers are stripped off. so you cannot send a bearer token with these calls.

Comment: I was referring to getting the current users email address using the Contacts API. Since the gadget is already authorized to get contacts and does not require a consent, we can send the email address signing with open_social_id.

Comment: Even within the gadget, you do not know the current user's email address, only the open_social_id. You have to break out of the gadget's context with the popup to know the user's identity.

Comment: @koma can you provide a working gadget oauth2 example, this is not working for me.